# How to configure the database failover configuration in IBM BPM/WebSphereApplication Server

Tags: websphere, business-process-management

We have a Database fail over setup for BPM/WAS . DB2 is our Database.We have configured all the Automatic reroute connections and tuned the connection pool settings. But still, whenever the Database fail over happens, the apps are coming up extremely slow. (If we recyle the JVMs, the apps are coming up quickly. But without restarting the JVMs we would like to achieve the perfect Database failover and recovery scenario.) Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Kumar.

Comment: The BPM Messaging Engine has to shut down and restart when there is a DB outage (or DB failover). Can you verify if this is the problem?

Comment: Hi XSurgent, we are trying to avoid manual intervention. So looking for some solution without restarting the JVMs.

Comment: Consider using the `sib.msgstore.jdbcFailoverOnDBConnectionLoss` custom property. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjm_tunedbconn.html) for details.

Comment: How are you storing the transaction logs? I assume they are on a Network Storage? Is it NFSV4?